# Python list comprehension error

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to order a list into months

```
months = ["Jan", "Feb", "March", "April",
          "May", "June", "July", "Aug",
          "Sept", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
```

This function works but i would like to use list comprehension instead

```
def order(values):
    sorted = []
    for month in months:
        if month in values:
            sorted_.append(month)
    return sorted_

order(["April","Jan", "Feb"]
```

**output - ['Jan', 'Feb', 'April']**

I tried this but i get a syntax error and i am not sure why

```
sorted_ = [month if month in values for month in months]
```

Comment: It looks like your `if` is in the wrong place:  `sorted_ = [month for month in months if month in values]`

Comment: @mgilson life saver!

Comment: You don't actually need a comprehension for this... `sorted(values,key=months.index)`. But each `list.index` call is O(n)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I never knew about this, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different ways to do conditionals in list comprehensions, and it depends on whether you have an `else` clause:

Without else clause:

```
[x for x in y if x == z]
[result for element in list if conditional]
```

With else clause:

```
[x if x == z else -x for x in y]
[result if conditional else alternative for element in list]
```

Note: These can also be combined:

```
[x if x.name == z else None for x in y if x is not None]
[result if conditional2 else alternative for element in list if conditional1]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
total_result = []
for x in y:
    if conditional1:
        if conditional2:
            total_result.append(result)
        else:
            total_result.append(alternative)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
values = ["Sept","Oct"]

sorted_ = [month for month in months if month in values]
```

Your list comprehension syntax was off a bit.